# How can I mass rename files containing Tilde (~) in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm renaming files in VBA using the following code

```
Sub Dateien_umbenennen()

Dim xDir As String
Dim xFile As String
Dim xRow As Long
Dim oFSO As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xDir = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F4").Value)
xFile = Dir(xDir & "\" & "*")

Do Until xFile = ""
xRow = 0

On Error Resume Next
xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)

If xRow > 0 Then
Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
xDir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
End If

xFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Old name in column A, new name in column B, folder specified by the value in cell F4. Some files in column A contain the ~ special character. Those files are not being renamed while the ones that don't have the character are. How can I rename the files that contain the ~ ?

Comment: Do them containing the character inside the file name string, or as the first character?

Comment: Do those files really have a tilde (~) in the names, or are they short versions of a long file names? I am referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: They are inside the file name string

Comment: Example for a file name: ZBPD_1121630.4-04_WGR_(B~~76)_c_Z_0562_1v1. Maybe I should say that the new name would look like this ZBPD_1121630.4-04_WGR_(B##76)_c_Z_0562_1v1 (also with special character)

Comment: There's an add-in that does batch renaming of files, it's called AuthorTec File Doctor, Do a web search for more info. I am the author and it's free for 30-days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that issue in xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0). If you locate the row with, for example, name~1.txt, its need next syntax: xRow = Application.Match("name~~1.txt", Range("A:A"), e.g. double ~. Try this code: `xRow = Application.Match(Replace(xFile,"~","~~"), Range("A:A"),0)`

Comment: Thank you! Now the files are being renamed